# Perl class naming convention

Tags: perl

Let's say I create a class named `Bar`. The file `Bar.pm` starts

```
package Bar;
```

To avoid colliding with other `Bar` classes, I put the file in a subdirectory `Foo`. So now, when I use the class, I have to write

```
use Foo::Bar;
```

My question is, **do I need to change the name of the class to `Foo::Bar`?** In other words, do I need to change the first line of `Bar.pm` to

```
package Foo::Bar;
```

? The problem is, if I do this, I now have to refer to the class as `Foo::Bar` everywhere, e.g.

```
my $obj = Foo::Bar->new();
Foo::Bar->doClassMethod();
```

which is annoying (the same problem was discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430548/how-can-i-call-a-perl-class-with-a-shorter-name)), especially since I am fond of class methods.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you have to change the name of the `package` to exactly match that of the `use`.

Comment: Can you expand on the meaning of "have to" a little? I ask because it works (compiles and runs) **without** changing the package name. What are the consequences of not changing it?

Comment: @shawkinaw If you don’t, then the `use` statement’s `import` method will not find the right class, and other class methods including constructors will (often) misfire. It’s like getting the case wrong in the `use` statement. It kinda works on case-insensitive filesystems, but only by accident, and all kinds of other stuff gets hosed. Don’t do that. Just make your file, package, and use all line up exactly. Years from now you might have some reason to do something else, but that comes only with severe and battle-word experience. It’s still dubious.

Answer (score 2):

If you think having a class name `Bar` might conflict with other classes named `Bar` then simply moving the file won't help. If your program eventually uses both `Bar` and `Foo::Bar` then both will have been loaded into the same namespace. At that point what happens to your program is anyone's guess.

If don't want to type long class names then you can use a variable to hold the name.

```
use My::Long::Class::Name::For::Bar; 
my $bar_class = 'My::Long::Class::Name::For::Bar'; 

$bar_class->class_method(); # the same as My::Long::Class::Name::For::Bar->class_method()
```

Comment: True, but presumably you wouldn't load two different `Bar` classes at the same time. But I see your point. It would be nice if Perl let you refer to classes by a shortened name, but only if there was no ambiguity. Tcl, for all its faults, lets you invoke procedures by a shortened name as long as it is unique.

Answer (score 1):

You don't strictly need to (i.e. it's a style decision, not something the compiler enforces), but it is a good idea to follow the relevant guidelines set out in perlmod/perlnewmod to make the software easily distributable.

IOW, if long names bother you, get an editor with autocompletion.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [`perldoc -f require`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html):

> If EXPR is a bareword, the require assumes a ".pm" extension and
>   replaces "::" with "/" in the filename for you, to make it easy to
>   load standard modules. This form of loading of modules does not risk
>   altering your namespace. In other words, if you try this:
>
> ```
>     require Foo::Bar;     # a splendid bareword
> ```
>
> The require function will actually look for the "Foo/Bar.pm" file in the
>   directories specified in the @INC array.

So, yes, it's convention that if your module is located at `$dir/Foo/Bar.pm` for some `$dir` in [`@INC`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html), then it must be called `Foo::Bar`.

Answer (score 0):

The package `Local` is reserved just for this use. For example, if you create a package `Bar.pm`, you could call the package `Local::Bar` and know it won't clash with something in CPAN.

By default, `@INC` includes the current directory, so you could create a `Local` subdirectory, and then put all of your packages there. In a company, I'll divide up the `Local` package namespace into groups and even names of the developers. For example, I could use `Local::Cm::Bar` or `Local::David::Bar`. That way, if I decide I could use Alice's Bar class, I could simply include `Local::Alice::Bar`.

Yes, the standard CPAN rules state not to use your name in package namespaces, but `Local` packages never go into CPAN.